# ¿Cómo Recuperar Espacio en Disco después de Truncar Tabla Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

En una base de datos tenia una tabla que era utilizada para guardar historial de algunas operaciones la cual contenía una gran cantidad de registro.

[image: Descripcion de Tabla]

Procedí a truncar la tabla para la eliminación de registro con el objetivo de recuperar el espacio en disco utilizado por la misma, sin embargo no hubo recuperación de espacio. Cabe mencionar que antes de truncar las tablas había reducido el log de transacciones lo cual si me recupero espacio.

Quisiera pudieran indicarme que debo realizar para recupera el espacio de dicha tabla que segun la descripcion es de aproximadamente **98.25 GB**

Comment: LAMENTO DECIRTE QUE TODA LA INFORMACIÓN QUE TENIAS YA NO ESTARA YA QUE EL TRUNCATE SOLO LIMPIA LA TABLA Y TE MUESTRA EL MISMO ESPACIO POR QUE TAL VËZ AUN NO REFRESCA EL TAMAÑO REAL EL SISTEMA.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server Management Studio tiene la opcion de reducir el tamaño de la base de datos, es simple, mira esta imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego das OK y listo. Tambien puedes reducir el tamaño de tablas individuales.

Answer (score 0):

**Reclamar espacio en disco**

Al usar Truncate para obtener más espacio es valido mientras la tabla halla sido creada con la opción "innodb_file_per_table=ON". Lo que hace esto es que genera un solo archivo para manejar toda la información de dicha tabla y al realizar el truncate lo elimina y crea uno nuevo, liberando el espacio en disco deseado.

Comment: Si en dado caso la tabla no se hubiese creado con la opción que me comentas  ¿existe alguna otra forma de recuperar el espacio en disco?  Algun Script o mediante el asistente de alguna opción del Management Studio.

Comment: `innodb_file_per_table=ON` me imagino es para MySQL, la pregunta es sobre SQL Server, te sugiero reformular tu respuesta  o eliminarla. Saludos.